# Should I manually install all my system wide packages after upgrading to Python 3?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

I have some systemwide packages I've installed and I'm unclear whether I'm supposed to install another copy of them all for Python3 or if there is some way to 'point' Python3 at them. I'm on a Mac.

I still have Python 2.7.9 which has all the packages (most installed with either brew or pip and maybe one or two manually like pyqt). Do I basically have to redo the installation process for every single package again? Or is there some way to simply have Python3 'inherit' everything I've installed so far under 2.7.9?

Also, from what I understand, to install under Python3 with pip I would use pip3 install, is that correct? How would I do the same with ones installed with Homebrew? Is there a brew3 command? Or does Homebrew install to all versions of Python?

Comment: Python3 is not backward compatible with python2 so yes you will have to reinstall all  the packages you want to use with python 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need to reinstall, but I would step away from systemwide installs in general and start using project-specific package installation.

Use [`pyenv`](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) for version switching and [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) for isolated environments.

Comment: Thanks. I'm starting to use virtualenv more (still trying to understand how pyenv is different). But for the few I want systemwide (like virtualenv itself) it sounds like I want to install that again with pip3.

Comment: Btw, do you know how/can Homebrew packages work with virtualenvs? There are a few packages I found that are on homebrew and not on pip, what is the best way to deal with these?

Comment: If you've installed python via Homebrew, `brew install` will install into the site-packages for the brew python installation. I'd still suggest installing to a virtualenv instead; you can try to download the packages directly and install via the usual `python setup.py install` instead of using brew for those.

Answer (score 0):

pyvenv works rather well.

Install Python 3

```
python -m venv "my_virtual_env"
my_virtual_env\Scripts\activate
pip search lib
pip install ...
```

You will have to look up what the activate command is for osx. pip is the standard package manager now. You can search, install, and uninstall with pip. Pip is also moving towards wheels when installing packages. You probably don't have to worry about wheels too much though.